# Is is possbile to put a png over admob banner on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am a designer. And I have question, is it possible to realize "remove ad button" like on the picture? So the png layer is over ad banner?

https://skitch.com/e-guanxsi/edi4s/removead

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why no, just place a `UIButton` above the `UIView` in which you will load the banner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is easily possible, programmer just need to add a button over his content view.